# Image 360º with Jquery Reel: extra steps per loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, 3d, jquery-reel

I have this set of images, wich are 109. Its a room spining 360º from 3 different (vertical) prespectives.

It seems to work ok, but i don't know why at the end of each loop i get to see some steps/frames from another prespective:

Its easier if you just check: http://toniweb.us/m/3d/adam.html

And this is how i am calling it:

```
$('#room').reel({ 
          frames:  36,         /*   frames  per spin */
          rows:    3,          /*   prespectives     */
          columns: 36,
          speed:   0.2,
          brake: 5,
         /* cw: true,*/
          path:    'object/', 
          images:  get_frames() ,   /* Array with all images */
          indicator: 10,
          wheelable: false,
          steps: 36               /* frames per spin*/
});
```

am i making a wrong use of frames, rows,coumns and steps? or the problem is in the images?

thanks a lot

Comment: Have no definitive answer for you, but still. First, there's no `columns` option in Reel. And `steps` are essentially `frames`, so you can leave out `steps` too. Other options are fine. Second, I noticed that running `get_frames().length` in your example gives `108`, not `109` as you indicated, so double check by hand what this function outputs for you. Also problem in images still possible..